# Difference between "Identity providers" and "authentication providers"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I don't get the difference between the `User Pools > Identity providers` and 
`Federated Identities > Authentication providers`.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity pools (Federated identities) allow you to grant users authenticated by third parties (e.g. login with Google) temporary IAM credentials to use you AWS resources in a limited way. Identity pools are free of cost and you only pay for the resources your users use via the IAM credentials.

User pools allow you to store your own users, they can sign up directly to the user pool and not have to use a third party provider like Google or Facebook. Confusingly user pools also have a 'federation' option (Identity providers) but this will actually create externally federated users in the pool. User pools provide OpenID tokens (access, id, refresh), not IAM credentials, which you can use with your own endpoints (ec2, fargate, api-gateway). User pools have costs associated with them based on the active users per month.